# Laravel localization problems 5.2+

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my middleware.

```
class BeforeMiddleware{

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Perform action

    App:setLocale(LC_ALL,Session::get('locale'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

If i don't place LC_ALL as first parameter in setLocale i get this error.

> "setlocale() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given"

If i put LC_ALL as the first parameter localization doesn't change.
Version of laravel is 5.2+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've change App::setLocale to app()->setLocale(Session::get('locale')); and looks like it works fine.

Comment: This also works when you try to use it in controllers.

Comment: tha is wrong ... the correct answer is at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

setlocale with out capital L this function is php function which takes 2 parameters in laravel you have to use App::setLocale with two colons ...